# Why is the "bounty eligible in ? hours" message missing?

Tags: support, bounties

Why does [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85832/find-the-missing-number) on Puzzling Stack Exchange not have the bounty link whereas the others on the sites do? ([example](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85608/not-just-black-and-white))

Even if it is not 2 days old yet, shouldn't it have the link that says "bounty eligible in ? hours"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; you only see that link on your own questions (the second question you mention is yours; [I don't see the message there either](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kvJS.png)). The bounty function is not *that* important and if you see that message on *every* new question you visit, well, it just isn't worth the whitespace it is taking.

If you happen to have [one of my userscripts](https://stackapps.com/q/7722/34061) installed, you would see such a message (though its wording is a little different).